# python unicode woes - convert cp1252 string to unicode

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, ms-office, cp1252

I think I'm just fundamentally confused about char sets that are not ascii.

I have a python file that I have declared at the top to be `# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-`.

In the file I have `question = "what is your borther’s name"`, for example.

`type(question)`

>> str

`question`

>> 'what is your borther\xe2\x80\x99s name'

And I cannot convert to unicode at this point, presumably because you can't go from ASCII to Unicode.

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)

if I declare as unicode to begin with:

`question = "what is your borther’s name"`

>> u'what is your borther\u2019s name'

How do I get "what is your borther’s name" back? Or is just a how python interpreter displays unicode strings and it in fact will encode correctly when I pass it to an unicode-aware application (in this case, Office)?

I need to preserve the special characters but I still need to do a string comparison using Levenshtein library (`pip install python-Levenshtein`).

Levenshtein.ratio takes str or unicode for both of its arguments, but not mixed.

Comment: unicode(mystring.decode("cp1252")), does it work?

Comment: no it seems like once the string is ascii it will not convert back to unicode. see my edits above.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a plain text file that I have declared at the top to be `# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-`.

That does nothing.

```
with codecs.open(..., encoding='cp1252') as fp:
   ...
```